# How to read a file of variable name from a directory in C?

Tags: c

I am running a C code first to list all the files of a directory into a temporaryfile as,

```
system("cd data;    ls -t -r *.txt > temporaryfile; sort -V temporaryfile > temporaryfile1;cd ..");
```

The contents of temporaryfile is, 0.txt,1.txt,...
Now I have to read all the files 0.txt, 1.txt, ... one by one in order to analyze the results. The process I am following is to read the names of 0.txt,... into an array of strings, then supply that into fopen as,

```
char ctt[50];char str[50];const char *FF[10000];

line=0;fp = fopen("./data/temporaryfile1", "r");
while(fgets(str, strl, fp) != NULL){    
    line++;
    sscanf(str,"%s",ctt);
    char cttt[] = "./data/";
    FF[line-1]=strcpy(cttt, ctt);
    printf("%s\n",FF[line-1]); // this prints 0.txt, 1.txt, ... correctly
    }fclose(fp);

    printf("%s",FF[0]);         //prints nothing
    fp = fopen(FF[0], "r");
    fclose(fp);                 // here I am getting segmentation fault as FF[0] is not ./data/0.txt which I was expecting
```

This is error is for sure because of string handling, Kindly suggest to how to rectify the error.

Comment: `FF[line-1]=strcpy(cttt, ctt);` That has multiple problems. Firstly, `cttt` is sized to fit exactly `"./data/"`. Trying to copy anything longer into that buffer will overflow it. Secondly, `cttt` scope is one iteration of the `while` loop. `FF` is storing the  value, `cttt` for every entry which becomes invalid at the end of the `while` loop.

Comment: yes this is exactly what is happening, FF is printing correct value inside the while loop, but just after the loop it looks that it is having the value of a character space " ". But how to get outside the loop, FF[0]=0.txt

Comment: Use strdup instead of strcpy. Don't forget to free the memory allocated by strdup when done with it.

Comment: You don't need all those external programs to get a list of files in a directory... Look into `scandir()` and `glob()` among others...